# Unit testing $(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function called `watch`, which looks something like:

```
function watch(interaction) {
    $(document).on(interaction.event, interaction.selector, function() {
        ...
    });
}
```

My thinking was to spy on `$(document).on()` and check that it's been called with the arguments I pass it:

```
it('should watch events on DOM elements', function() {
    var $doc = $(document);

    spyOn($doc, 'on');

    watch({ event: 'click', selector: '#foo' });

    expect($doc.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('click', '#foo', jasmine.any(Function));
});
```

Jasmine tells me that `$doc.on` is never called, however. My thinking is that this is because `$doc` in the test refers to a different instance than `$(document)` inside `watch()`.

If that's the case, how can I test to make sure `watch()` is wiring up `$(document).on()` correctly?

Comment: You could mock `$` so that calling it always returns the same object with the same `.on` mock method. You might want to look at jest, which is built on top of jasmine: http://facebook.github.io/jest/ .

Comment: Please submit mocking $ as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mock `$` so that calling it always returns the same object with the same `.on` mocked method. This makes sense since you don't want to test jQuery itself.

I haven't done any mocking with Jasmine so I cannot provide a concrete example. You might want to look at jest, which is built on top of Jasmine and mocks every module by default: https://facebook.github.io/jest .